# Calling SQL commands for MS Access from Java is very slow the first time and much faster on subsequent runs

Tags: java, sql, performance, connection

I'm connecting to an Access database with a jdbc:odbc bridge.
I then select a large amount of data from the database (~2 million rows).
The first time I run the code after a restart it is very slow, taking over 6 minutes to retrieve the data.
On subsequent runs, it takes only 1.5 mins to do the same thing.

This is the code I'm using to connect to the database:

```
try {
        Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
        String url = "jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=" + databaseLocation + databaseName + ";selectMethod=cursor; READONLY=true; TYPE=FASTLOAD";

        con = DriverManager.getConnection(url);

        System.out.println("Connected to " + databaseName);

        } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("SQL Exception: " + e.toString());   
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException cE) {
        System.out.println("Class Not Found Exception: " + cE.toString());
    }
```

After much Googling I've tried adding parameters such as

```
selectMethod=cursor
READONLY=true
TYPE=FASTLOAD
```

As far as I can see, none of these made a difference.

I then select the data like so:

```
String SQL = "SELECT ADDRESS_MODEL.ADDR_LINE_1, ADDRESS_MODEL.ADDR_LINE_2, LOCALITIES.NAME, ADDRESS_MODEL.SECONDARY_LOCALITY, TLANDS.NAME, ADDRESS_MODEL.POST_TOWN, ADDRESS_MODEL.COUNTY FROM ((ADDRESS_MODEL LEFT JOIN BUILDINGS ON ADDRESS_MODEL.BUILDING_ID = BUILDINGS.BUILDING_ID) LEFT JOIN LOCALITIES ON BUILDINGS.LOCALITY_ID = LOCALITIES.LOCALITY_ID) LEFT JOIN TLANDS ON BUILDINGS.TLAND_ID = TLANDS.TLAND_ID WHERE BUILDINGS.COUNTY_ID = " + county_ID;

    PreparedStatement prest = con.prepareStatement(SQL);

    ResultSet result = prest.executeQuery();
```

I tried using a prepared statement but I'm not sure I did it right.

After storing the data I close the ResultSet:

```
result.close();
```

Later in the program, I close the connection as follows:

```
try{
        stmt.close();
        con.close();
        System.out.println("Connection to " + databaseName + " closed");
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("SQL Exception: " + e.toString()); 
    }
```

Unfortunately I am committed to using both Java and Access at this point.

Does anyone have any idea why it is slower the first time (or more why it is faster on subsequent runs)?
Also, are there any general things I could do better to make it faster?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Pretty much any database will be slower the first time.

Comment: Why is that though? If I'm correctly closing the connection to the database surely it has to start again from scratch. Is the data still held in RAM somehow?

Comment: Besides building caches, there are a lot of other stuff going on under the hood too, like evaluating plans and other activities that makes subsequent runs go faster.

Answer (score 0):

You say two million rows, but how large is the data?  It's quite possible that it's reading it all in from disk the first time, then it's in the disk cache for subsequent runs.  Even if the entire dataset doesn't fit in RAM at once, it's likely that key data structures will still be present.

Comment: Interesting. The Access database is about 1GB in size. I'm not reading all of it in by any means though. I'm not really sure how to estimate the size of the data I actually take. Maybe 10% of it.